# Flask-SQLAlchemy create_all doesn't create the tables in sqlite3

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am learning Flask and I created a project today to try Flask-SQLAlchemy. After I executed create_all, no error was reported but the tables were not created in sqlite3.

Below is the directories and files of my project.

```
flasktest
  -- flasktest
       -- controllers
            -- home.py
       -- views
            -- home
                -- index.html
       -- __init__.py
       -- extensions.py
       -- models.py
       -- settings.py
  -- wsgi.py
```

Below is the code of wsgi.py

```
from flasktest import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Below is the code of __init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flasktest.settings import config
from flasktest.extensions import db
from flasktest.controllers.home import home_bp


def create_app(config_name=None):
    if config_name is None:
        config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'development')
    app = Flask(import_name="flasktest", template_folder="views")
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)


def register_blueprints(app):
    app.register_blueprint(home_bp)
```

Below is the code of extensions.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Below is the code of models.py

```
from flasktest.extensions import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Below is the code of settings.py

```
import os


basedir = os.path.abspath((os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class BaseConfig(object):
    SECRET_KEY = "mysecret"
    DEBUG = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, 'production.db')


config = {'development': DevelopmentConfig, 'production': ProductionConfig}
```

Then I entered flask shell, and I typed the following commands:

```
from flasktest.extensions import db
db.create_all()
```

No error was reported. However, the User table was not created. Does anybody know what's wrong with my code? Thanks!